# Is it acceptable for a moderator to delete my useful comments?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

Here's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745199/fast-gaussian-blur-at-pause-in-cocos2d-x-v3-15) question about creating a fast variable-width gaussian blur in cocos2d.

For this, one first has to find a good, fast algorithm, then one must implement it in cocos2d. As I know a fast algorithm for this, but I don't know cocos2d, I have written two middle-sized comments describing the algorithm.

Then, this happened: OP didn't believe that my algorithm works (they said something like: "I should try my recommendations before answering", as my solution is "ugly", and "all wrong"), then I explained why they were wrong. Then, a moderator deleted all my comments, even the two describing the algorithm.

I asked the moderator (in the comments) to undelete my two comments, as they are useful. They said something like "I need to avoid discussion in the comments". Then I explained that they should at least undelete the first two comments, as they are useful. Then all my comments got deleted again, without any response, why.

I'd happily put my deleted comments here (to see it for youself), but as they are deleted, I can't see them.

What do you think about this? It's a very bad experience for me: first, I try to help, OP responds (moderately) rudely, then a moderator deletes my comments, without proper explanation (i.e. why my two middle-sized comments are "lengthy conversation").

Not to mention, that the only current answer to the question is far from optimal, my described algorithm is much much faster.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, subject to deletion at ANY time, for almost any reason. If the information is important and useful, make it live in answers.

Comment: So, yes, it's *acceptable*, regardless of whether or not it was warranted.

Comment: @Patrice: what's the reason of this?

Comment: Were your comments requests for clarity? If you seem to have a better solution, what prevents you from answering the question?

Comment: @E_net4: because I could only answer a little part of the question. It wouldn't be an answer, just a useful hint, how to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Generally comments are used to request clarification from the OP.  If you want to propose an alternative solution that is what the answer box is for.  Even if the solution is not complete it still counts as an answer

Comment: It would be an answer, potentially even a useful one. It just wouldn't necessarily be complete

Comment: If you can only *answer* a part of the question, maybe the question is too broad?

Comment: If you believe your algorithm is better, post it as an answer.

Comment: @geza because comments are second-class citizens on Stack Exchange. Stack was meant as a question & answer site, PERIOD. The comments were added afterwards because sometimes they are needed to clarify questions. They are still to be considered temporary

Comment: I'd take that as a hint that the question might be too broad. That and the fact that the only effective question inside the question was "is that right way to do?". I will leave it to the experts nevertheless.

Comment: @Patrice: there are hell a lot of information in comments. Plus, a lot of comments are actually answers. At least, that's the current practice on SO.

Comment: In my opinion the question **is** too broad. I don't see any way how it could be answered without implementing the whole thing (someone did that and posted an answer), but basically that question is a just specification and the question how to solve it. Wonder how that thing got 9 upvotes.

Comment: @geza yes. The fact that some people use comments like that doesn't mean it's their intended use. And it doesn't change anything about my point.... You want to know if it's acceptable that the comments got deleted. I just told you what comments are supposed to be and why you should never assume they WON'T be deleted. You can disagree... that doesn't change the gist of what I said. (note: I know a lot of useful comments are kept, and they should be kept. But the fact it happens here and there doesn't mean that this is what comments were meant for)

Comment: @Patrice, thanks for the information. For reference, here's the doc about comments: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment. If these are the rules, SO should enforce them somehow, as comments are often used for answers (actually, some high rep person encouraged me, if I cannot put a proper answer, but I have something to add to a question, then I should put this information into a comment - now, according this doc, this is a bad habit on SO).

Comment: @geza It's such a common practice, with plenty of comments sticking around for years, that it makes me wonder how much the others here pay attention to how the site is actually used.  I would've also recommended that, if you can't actually answer the question but could point someone else to an answer (such as you describe here), a comment is exactly the right way to do it.

Comment: Nice to know the "comments are ephemeral" meme is alive and well.

Comment: @BoltClock Curious so I Googled *"comments are ephemeral" meme* I couldn't find it.

Comment: @zer00ne: I haven't bothered to add the entry to The Many Memes of Meta yet. But anyone who's been around on meta for a while knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Izkata: exactly. If people doesn't use comments as intended, then **SO creators should consider changing the rules about them**. Clearly, comments are used **very** differently than written in the doc. A **lot** of comments are used to throw in some information about the subject, and they are not clearifying requests. SO would be a much worse information source, if any comments could be deleted without any reason. In my opinion, "comments are ephemeral" is a wrong approach.

Comment: @Izkata: even, look at the first comment under this question. Does it adhere the rules about comments? No, it is actually an answer to my question. Because it is so natural to throw in some information in a comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not candidate for moderator this year?

Comment: @Cœur Not this go around.  I had taken some time off from SO and I'm still getting back into the swing of things.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

What happened was that we got in a large number of flags on the comments there, so it popped to the top of the moderator queue. The moderator who acted on this most likely saw the argument that had developed after your original constructive comments, all the flags there, and decided to purge everything to clean it all up.

You weren't at fault here, and your two original comments were useful (I wrote the project under discussion here), so I undeleted them. You didn't deserve the rude comments you received from the asker.

However, others have made the point that maybe you could combine these into an answer if you wanted to make sure they stuck around. Comments are deleted regularly when they devolve into arguments, and what you propose could make for a viable answer. I know that you aren't as confident in a full process, which is why these were left as comments, but what you describe would stand as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad, your professional answer (one who actually cares what's happened) restored some faith in this site (I'm very close to quitting, because of the bad experience...).

Comment: @geza - Yeah, sorry they got so hostile about your suggestion. No idea why that happened. For the record, your suggestion is what I've seen several people do for animated blurs.

Comment: @geza, don't quit, just stick around for moderator elections and ensure helpful peacemakers become moderators, and not banhammer-ers.

Comment: @geza I've been on Stackoverflow since 2009 I think... and this is something that often happens. So your best bet is just to suck it up and hope there will be more moderators like Brad. If it gets too toxic - just take some time off and come back when you feel like you can deal with negativity.